# Eclipse Localhost to download File

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets, download

I have installed Tomcat version 7.0 , now I have a .pdf file in my Tomcat Root folder, which I can directly access from firefox when tomcat server is running, using the link: localhost:8080/filename.pdf

Now, I have written a Java Servlet code, which when executed on eclipse produces a link (localhost:8080/filename.pdf), now on clicking that link I am getting Error 404, resource not found.

Any idea , how to resolve this ???

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: It is not a problem with the code I think.. When Tomcat is running, http://localhost:8080/1.pdf is opening just fine, but when Eclipse is running, the same path shows 'HTTP 404 Resource Not Found' error.

Comment: Did you create a server project for Tomcat in Eclipse? The issue may be that it is using a context path other than ROOT when running from Eclipse. Check your server config.

Comment: How to check the server Configuration ? For both eclipse and the tomcat...

Comment: It depends how you run it. Do you have a Server project in Eclipse?

Comment: Look into `your_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0`.